# Set Different Margin Color in Libreoffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer, margins, background

Is it possible to set different margin color and leave the workspace white ?? Because some text and pictures need to add there..
I look up and haven't found anything related to this except for this article which is completely opposite from what i want.
[How do I set the paper color in LibreOffice Writer?](https://superuser.com/questions/468824/how-do-i-set-the-paper-color-in-libreoffice-writer)

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done on a per-document basis without a background image by using a frame. Whether the result can be printed without an unprinted margin will depend on capabilities of the printer.

First, in `Page Style...`, set the margins on the Page tab and also set the color of of the margins on the Area tab. This will set the whole page background to the selected color.

Then, select `Insert > Frame > Frame...` and do the following:

1. Click the *Type* tab and...

- In the **Anchor** section, select 'To paragraph'
- In the **Size** section:

  - uncheck 'AutoSize' and 'Keep ratio' settings
  - set both Width and Height to 100% relative to 'Paragraph area'
- In the **Position** section

  - uncheck both boxes
  - set both Horizontal and Vertical to 'Center' and 'Page text area'

In short, the resulting settings should look like this...
[image: Frame dialog box Type tab settings]

2. Click the *Wrap* tab and set all **Spacing** values to 0.0.
3. Click the *Borders* tab and click the leftmost **Line Arrangement** Preset to select no borders.
4. Click the Area tab and set the color to white.

The page should now consist of a white document area and color margin.

Finally, put all of your document content into the frame.
[image]

Comment: It's Fabuloso man.. I'm soo grateful Compadre. StackExchange power..

Answer (score 0):

In `Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Application Colors > Custom Colors > Application background`, you can set the background of the margin. If you want to set other colors, you can also change them here. After you are finished, you can save as a custom color scheme to reuse later.

Comment: It makes the whole background colored of libreoffice writer except the document itself . What i want is to have 4 margins colored in my document.

Comment: so you want the (inner) edges of the page to be a custom color right? If so, I believe you may have to set it on a per-document basis (maybe a default could be set, but existing documents may need to be changed by hand)

Comment: could you explain me how i should do it ?

Comment: @Jims-Rc You can set the document background in `Custom Colors > Document Background` and override that at `Format > Page (Alt+Shift+P) > Page` and deselect `Background covers margins`, then go to `Area` (in the same window) and select a custom color (overrides setting in Custom Colors). Not that I would recommend this as Page formats are saved in the document and custom colors are saved in Writer. But if you need this, it is kinda possible.

Comment: no. i want outside edges. sorry for the inconvenience. here i uploaded the file. please check. [ https://ibb.co/1d28rwq ] I'm not very fond of office in general man. just started to learn libreoffice. doing this for practice.

Comment: @Jims-Rc so you would like to set a style that is printable right?, In that case, looking at MS word's templates they are using a picture as the border. You could also set a border but it would only be a line